# How do i display the first modified date instead of the Last Modified Date

Tags: date, modified

I want to a column to display when a record is first modified. SharePoint defaults the modified date to the last modified date. My goal is to also have a column when it was first modified so i can calculate Turn around Time.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint only stores "Created" and "Modified" dates. If not date created, what is your definition of first modified? If it is the first edit after the item was created, then create a workflow.

- Triggers on change/update
- Checks to see if a custom column named "First Modified" is blank, and if not stores the current date and time to "First Modified".